# Asp.Net strongly typed views and html re

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a strongly typed view that is working and receives the model sent from the controller.

As well as the model data, I need to record what the user has clicked from a set of checkboxes.  These checkboxes are created as the view is loaded but are not bound to the Model.

With a normal form submit (post), wouldn't the checkbox values be added to the HTTP message body?

With the strongly typed view this does not seem to happen.

Is it possible for the users selections to get sent back to the controller in addition to the model somehow?

Update:
Sorry if this unclear. Basically I have 2 repositories of data - one is my own custom database which stores records of user interaction and the other is a cms.

The cms hold the data that is used to generate the checkboxes and the database stores the data that is used to generate the model that is bound to the view.

In my model I have an id that I can use to query the cms to get the data needed to generate the checkboxes so this gets done in the view. That is why the count and the names of the checkboxes are not known in advance.

I need to store the cb vales as a comma separated list intje db so that OS why unwed to query form data.

Turns out it is really easy...

Request.Form

does the trick

Comment: Some code would help. However my first question would be why not add these properties to the model and bind the checkboxes to them? That is how MVC works. If the concern with adding them is the fact that the model is used elsewhere, this is an issue of separation of concerns; the view model should be used for the view only and following this convention would eliminate that problem.

Comment: The trouble is that the checkboxes are not known in advance of generating the view.  They are created within the view.

Comment: Even with dynamically generated data there are ways to bind to the model. Please review the SO guidelines for posting questions - if you  share your code you are more likely to get a helpful answer.

Answer (score 1):

You should add the checkboxes as properties of you strongly typed object.

The values are returned in the response form data. But addding the properties is best. If you cant add the properties directly to the class use a partial class.

Comment: how would I get to them in the response form data from the controller

Answer (score 1):

You can add properties for the checkboxes in the model, then they would be populated from the form data.

You can also add parameters for the checkboxes in the action method, then they would be populated from the form data. Example:

```
public ActionResult MyAction(MyModel model, bool check1, bool check2) {
```

You can also pick up the values from the form data without defining any properties or parameters:

```
bool check1 = Request.Form["check1"] == "on";
bool check2 = Request.Form["check2"] == "on";
```

Answer (score 1):

2 options I can think of.

1. Just like @KevDevMan has said. Add it to the model. a bool value on the model will do. But in case you don't need this then try the next one.
2. Here is the next one. Giving those checkboxes unique name (name="chkbox1" , name="chkbox2") and adding those on the action as parameters with the same variable name(note from my experience I see that this is not case sensitive). So your action would be like this.

   ```
   public ActionResult AfterSumbit(MyModel model, bool chkbox1, bool chkbox2)
   ```

or if you want the value of the checkbox

```
    public ActionResult AfterSubmit(MyModel model, string chkbox1, string chkbox2)
```

this is done automatically by .net so rest assured that it will be placed to the variables accordingly.